# How to check whether some \catcode is \active?

Tags: catcodes

I'm going to change a catcode to `active` and then implement my own formatting of small verbs:

```
\if-not-active
  \catcode`|=\active
  \def|#1|{\foo{#1}}
\fi
```

I want to make this non-intrusive and check first, whether it's already active. If it is, make no changes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can access the category code of any character.

```
\ifnum\catcode`|=\active
  \typeout{BEWARE! The bar is active!}%
\else
  \catcode`|=\active
  \def|#1|{\foo{#1}}
\fi
```

TeX maintains a few arrays for the characters, indexed from 0 to 255 (or 0x10FFFF when using a Unicode engine)

```
\catcode
\lccode
\uccode
\sfcode
\mathcode
\delcode
```

Each entry in these arrays is an integer and you assign the values with

```
<array name><integer>=<integer>
```

For instance, plain TeX begins by assigning

```
\catcode`{=1
\catcode`}=2
```

so as to enable reading macro arguments. Other assignments are hardwired, for instance assigning category code 0 to the backslash or space factor code 999 to the uppercase letters.

How you denote the integers is irrelevant. For instance any of

```
\catcode`|=13
\catcode 124=13
\catcode`^^<=`\^^M
```

would be equivalent to

```
\catcode`|=\active
```

If TeX finds the name of one of those arrays when an assignment doesn't make sense, it interprets it as querying the value in a slot. Thus

```
\the\catcode`\\
```

will print 0. But already `` \catcode`| `` returns an integer that can be fed to `\ifnum` or in any place where TeX is expecting an integer.

A bit of overloading, but it's done for keeping TeX as small as possible and is not as mysterious as it can appear at the beginning.

---

Another case of overloading is with `\font`, the primitive for defining a control sequence to mean a font change. If you use `\font` where TeX is expecting a font switching command, it will point to the current font.

So if you want to query the width of A in the current font you can use

```
\fontcharwd\font`A
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\ifnum\catcode`\|=\active
yes
\else
no
\fi
```

(`\active` is just a shortcut for the number 13)